# fetching inside express server - fetch is not defined

Tags: express, facebook-graph-api, fetch

I am trying to get a long lived access token from facebook... according to the documentation, I need to fetch from the server side for security. If I fetch from the client side it works fine - but I should follow the guidelines.. Here is what I am doing - can you tell me why I get the server side error "Reference error: fetch is not defined"?

First I created a route from the front end to request the long lived token. To get the long lived token I need to use the short lived token so I send the short lived token in the req params. The variable userAccessTokenShort is valid and defined.

```
const newLongLivedUserAccessToken = await fetch(`/api/autoquotegenerators/longLivedUserToken/${userAccessTokenShort}`, {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
                "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
            },
        })
        const newLongUserTokenRes = await newLongLivedUserAccessToken.json()
        console.log(newLongUserTokenRes)
```

Then, on my express server, I made a route that handles the fetch request to the Facebook Graph API. This is where I get the reference error.

```
//Get Long Lived User Access Token on Backend /express route
router.get('/longLivedUserToken/:shortLived', (req, res) => {
    try {
        const getLongToken = fetch(`https://graph.facebook.com/v7.0/oauth/access_token?grant_type=fb_exchange_token&client_id=#############&client_secret=################&fb_exchange_token=${req.params.shortLived}`)
        .then(token => res.send(token))

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
})
```

If all goes well, the new token should be sent back to the client.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `fetch()` function built into node.js.  If you want something that looks pretty much like `fetch()` in the browser, you can look at the [`node-fetch` module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch) in NPM.

Or, there are [lots of modules](https://github.com/request/request/issues/3143) you can choose from in node.js.  My favorite is [`got()`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got).

FYI, the built-in interface for fetching http requests is `http.request()` or `http.get()`, but they are lower level and require more lines of code to do something simple than any of the above named modules.

Comment: Wow.. Ok! Now I know there is no fetch() built in! Got it to work and got a sweet response from the server. Thanks so much.